# pulling contact phone number issue

Tags: ios, swift

hi i have a class that pulls all the contacts. in debugger i see phone number like this: phone  String  "\U0000202a+111 11‑11‑11111\U0000202c"

when i print it, it shows 111 11-11-11111.

because of this i cant do `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)`

any idea why it gives me numbers like that , and is there a way to fix it ??

p.s = i use language that is right to left is it by any chance affects it

Comment: See this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's related to your right to left language. The codes are:

> [0x202a LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)
>   ...which tells the computer that the following string should go left to right.
>
> [0x202c POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm)
>   ...which tells the computer to go back to the previous text direction.

As how to get rid of them I don't know any specific method, but you should be able to just use normal string manipulation to eliminate them if they exist.

EDIT: An example how you could trim them using stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet;

```
str = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
           NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\u{202a}\u{202c}"))
```

Comment: @IgorSokolovsky Added an example.

Comment: i have another problem it wont remove this symbols () - and space why itryed like this                                                                                              `var str = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\u{202a}\u{202c}\u{0020}\u{002d}"))`                                                   and like this                                                                      `var stringTrim = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)` it dont work